# What determines order of precedence in occupation rights?

Tags: england-and-wales, tenancy-rules, eviction

Meet Alice.  Alice lets a house to Bob on a 6 month contract who then sublets it to Charles on a 12 month contract. Alice serves notice to the property addressed to Bob at the end of their term, which Charles ignores as it is not addressed to  him. She then obtains a possession order and then warrant. Bob unaware of all of this never informs  Charles of any of it, but  Bob's tenancy has been lawfully ended. Before he knows it bailiffs are showing up at Charles's door yet Charles has not been given any notice at all to leave.

It is commonly advised that the general rule is that when a mesne tenancy ends, any subtenancy of it too immediately ends which would mean that in the first scenario while Charles has protection from any unlawful eviction by Bob rooted in both common law and the human rights act, he is not fundamentally/comprehensively protected and that the possessor's ( Alice's) right to obtain possession trumps Charles's rights as a tenant to occupy and to receive notice. Why are  his human rights suddenly  inferior? It may be noted that in sightly different scenarios, the rules appear to be different. For example if he was subletting unlawfully and the effluxion of time transpires then he may become a trespasser, though if Bob had offered a surrender to Alice, then Charles would seem to automatically become Alice's direct lawful tenant with the correspondent protections.

Now meet Adam. Adam lets a house to Barbara and then signs a contract to sell it to Carroll empty. Barbara has nothing to worry about as she is in a tenancy contract guaranteeing her right to occupy which takes precedence over  Carroll's entitlement to buy the place empty. In this case tenant's occupancy rights appear to reign supreme, so it is tough stuff for Carroll, and perhaps even tougher stuff for Adam who will fail to fulfill his contract and probably become in breach.

What is the rule of law that dictates these two differing orders of precedence and outcomes?

Comment: Are his human rights interior or inferior?

Comment: It seems to me that Bob and Adam have both committed fraud by entering into contracts that they knew or should have known they would not be able to fulfill.  I'm not sure what bearing that has on Charles's occupancy, though.  Related, what was the cause of Charles's and Carroll's apparent failure to uncover Bob's six-month lease in the first case and Barbara's tenancy contract in the second?  Did they exercise insufficient diligence?  Would that have a bearing on the outcome?

Comment: Maybe fraud, maybe just ignorant naiveté, which is what I'd envisioned in both of the scenarios although more realistically so with the sale. Perhaps some miscommunication played a role thus necessitating a fallback onto the legal rules. In any event I think that any poor diligence or bad faith issues etc would be addressed on a completely separate basis as matters off possession are so closely regulated I don't think it would have a bearing on them. And yes, inferior, not interior.

Comment: +1 for actually using the word "precedence" with its correct meaning rather than in lieu of "precedents" as so many people at this site do.

Comment: Any time. - - -